# python library install Questions

Tags: python

I use Python and pycharm as a tool.
If you use the pip statement to install the library, you will get an error.
For example, if I want to download the torch (1.6.0) version and type pip install torch==1.6.0,
It says no version.
This is not the end, but some libraries continue to cause strange conflicts and will not be installed.
For example, if you type pip install poro to install the poro library, an unknown error pops up and the installation fails.
I'm not asking for a pororo installation.
My question is, I want to know how to download the library without relying on pycharm.
I want to download it separately from a site like pypi and put the library directly into the virtual environment (conda).
What should I do?

Comment: Please be more specific. Your Python version/Pip version/OS version + Errors you get including stacktraces and steps you take to get that error.

Comment: Please include the complete pip console output of the error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked for me:

First, install mkl using conda:

```
conda install -c anaconda mkl
```

Then run this:

```
conda install -c pytorch pytorch
```